Getting a TypeError in the .error function
I have been trying to get the error message after I have used ZOD for creating custom errors. But unfortunately getting the TypeError as the ".errors" is empty (as it says in the terminal).
I am new to MERN.
Error is generated in my validate-middleware.js file:
const validate = (schema) => async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const parseBody = await schema.parseAsync(req.body)
        req.body = parseBody
        next()
    } catch(e) {
        const status = 422
        const errorMessage = "Input is not given properly"
        const details = e.errors[0].messsage
        console.log(details)
        const error = {status, errorMessage, details}
        next(error)
    }
}

module.exports = validate

Error in terminal:
D:\2024\MERN\server\middleware\validate-middleware.js:9
        const details = e.errors[0].messsage
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at D:\2024\MERN\server\middleware\validate-middleware.js:9:33
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\2024\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\2024\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\2024\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:119:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\2024\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\2024\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (D:\2024\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (D:\2024\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (D:\2024\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
    at router (D:\2024\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

My Zod validation file - auth-validator.js
const loginValidation = z.object({
    email: z
        .string({required_error: "Email cannot be empty during Login"})
        .trim(),
    password: z
        .string({required_error: "Password cannot be empty during Login"})
    }
)


The error doesn't seem to be in the shape that you expected. You should debug and find out what exact error is being thrown. From the stack trace, it seems like the error is thrown when calling next()

You're assuming that e.errors is an array.  What the error message is telling you is that e.errors is undefined.   What your code is attempting to do is equivalent to this undefined[0].message  but undefined has no properties.
So to debug this you could simply comment out const details = e.errors[0].messsage then log console.log("E:: ", e) and see what is on the e object.
If during your debugging you find that e.errors is is ever undefined you can access it with conditional chaining like so e.errors?.[0]?.message  this allows us to ony try to access the index of e.errors if it is not undefined.  It also allows us to access the message property if e.errors[0] is also not undefined.
This is more of a javascript problem not a "MERN" problem.
